# Partial Designs are not visible on Page Design

Tags: sxa

We have installed Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8.

We created couple of partial and page designs and all was working fine.

We are using TDS to sync items between dev Sitecore instances.

After one of syncs, Partial designs are not working anymore.

We can see content in Partial Design itself:

[image]

But it's not visible in Page Design or Page which has that Partial Design selected:

[image]

This is for old and also for newly created Partial / Page Designs.

Is there some setting in Sitecore SXA that we have changed / overwritten accidentally?

How Partial designs end up in Page designs?

We have already rebuild all indexes and also link db just in case but no change.

Files are correct. We haven't changed those. We also don't have any custom pipeline. This must be something in Sitecore items.

Comment: Did you already verify the list of partial designs in the page design item?

Comment: Yes I did. We have also other Page Designs in the same site and they are also not working. If I create new site under same tenant, Page Designs are working as expected for that site.

Comment: I've had this before, it happened when a developer added a site to the site config that matched the same host name. So the site didn't run any of the SXA pipelines. Check that hasn't happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Richard's comment, I was able to identify the root cause.

During TDS sync some of the fields from \sitecore\content\%Tenant Name%\%Site Name%\Settings\Site Grouping\%Site Name% where not synced correctly (highlighted below) and were empty. I have filled them in and it is now working as expected:

[image]

Comment: Could be related to this issue discovered while using Unicorn. https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/issues/283

Comment: Seems like similar scenario that we encountered @MichaelWest. After we run sync again, field values were there.