# Partial design content not appearing in Page design

Tags: sxa

Using Sitecore 9.2 and SXA 1.9, I've created a Partial design which appears OK in the Experience Editor. I've then added the Partial design to a Page design but when I view that Page design in the Experience Editor, nothing is displayed. Why could that be?

I've seen this post but our site settings are correct:
[Partial Designs are not visible on Page Design](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16635/partial-designs-are-not-visible-on-page-design)

Comment: Can you verify that both the Partial Design and the Page Design have the same language and site in the url (sc_lang=<LANGUAGE>&sc_site=<SITE>) when editing in the Experience Editor?

Comment: All renderings form Partial Designs should be visible on the Page Design. But in general, you should not edit Page Design itself, it is only for grouping partials.

Comment: You can check the presentation details for the page design in Experience Editor. Select the layout for which the partial design contains the renderings. I guess you are checking in the layout in which there is no rendering for partial design. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnF1h.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnF1h.png)

Comment: @MathijsVlasveld yes, sc_lang and sc_site are the same across both

Comment: @DawidRutkowski the partial design isnt being displayed at all in the page design in the Experience Editor, and then in pages based off that page design ..

Comment: @RaghvendraMaheshwari They are both using Final Layout so that doesn't seem to be it

Comment: I've just open Page Design in EE and I see renderings which comes from partials. Please create a support ticket in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that we had TWO! extra `site definitions` in the config files that were causing this problem. As the site is configured in `/sitecore/content/Epworth/EpworthWeb/Settings/Site Grouping`, there is no need for site definitions in the config.

Removing them fixed this issue.